# Swift didReceiveRemoteNotification method

Tags: ios, swift, arguments

I have a problem with warning:

[image]

This method is from official documentation so I don't understand what's wrong with it (or implementation)

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if application.applicationState == .Inactive || application.applicationState == .Background {
            self.sendGoogleAnalyticsEventWithInfo(userInfo)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still warning in the second line (if application.applicationState == .Inactive || application.applicationState == .Background {)

Comment: Can you tell me your swift version ? 
For me, this works perfectly